# Rails 2.3 using another model's named_scope or alternative

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have two models like so:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  named_scope :about_x :conditions => "comments.text like '%x%')"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end
```

I would like to use the models so that I can return all the users and all comments with text like '%x%'

```
all_user_comments_about_x = User.comments.about_x
```

How to proceed?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you need

```
# all comments about x and the user who did it
@comments = Comment.about_x(:include => :user)
```

or

```
@user = User.first
# all @user's comments about x
@comments = @user.comments.about_x
```

Comment: thakns j, if I wanted to add a named_scope to the user model that used the about_x named scope of the comment model is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Try Following

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
  named_scope :about_x, :joins => :comments, :conditions => ["comments.text like '%x%'"]
end
```

and then

```
@comments = User.about_x
```